# combine two files to single file with combined columns

Tags: shell, text-processing, join

I need to combine two files into a single file with all columns from both files.

I am providing my example files.
**File 1**

```
chr loc T1  C1
chr1    100 2   3
chr1    200 3   4
chr2    100 1   4
chr2    400 3   1
```

**File 2**

```
chr loc T2  C2
chr1    100 1   2
chr1    300 4   1
chr2    100 7   5
chr2    500 1   9
```

and output file should be like this

**output file**

```
chr loc T1  C1  T2  C2
chr1    100 2   3   1   2
chr1    200 3   4   0   0
chr1    300 0   0   4   1
chr2    100 1   4   7   5
chr2    400 3   1   0   0
chr2    500 0   0   1   9
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
join -a1 -a2 -e 0 -o 0,1.2,1.3,2.2,2.3 \
    <(sed 's/ \+/_/' file1 | sort) \
    <(sed 's/ \+/_/' file2 | sort) | 
sed 's/_/ /' | 
column  -t | 
sort
```

```
chr   loc  T1  C1  T2  C2
chr1  100  2   3   1   2
chr1  200  3   4   0   0
chr1  300  0   0   4   1
chr2  100  1   4   7   5
chr2  400  3   1   0   0
chr2  500  0   0   1   9
```

The trickiest part here are the reasons for `sed` -- `join` will only join on a single field, and here the join criteria is the first 2 fields. So, we have to combine those fields into a single word: I replace the first sequence of whitespace with an underscore so join will see `chr1_100`, `chr1_200`, etc.

`join` requires its input files to be sorted.

I use [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution) so that `join` can work with the `sed|sort` pipelines like files.

Then another `sed` call to undo the combined field, and then `column` to make it pretty.

By default, `join` uses the first field of each file as the key field.

By default, `join` does an [inner join](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins): only keys present in both files are printed. The `-a1` and `-a2` option enable the full outer join we want. The `-e` option provides the default value for null fields, and we need the `-o` option to specify that we want all the fields.

---

Can also use awk:

```
awk '
    {key = $1 OFS $2} 
    NR == FNR {f1[key] = $3; f2[key] = $4; next} 
    !(key in f1) {print $1, $2, 0, 0, $3, $4; next} 
    {print key, f1[key], f2[key], $3, $4; delete f1[key]} 
    END {for (key in f1) print key, f1[key], f2[key], 0, 0}
' file1 file2 | sort
```

```
chr loc T1 C1 T2 C2
chr1 100 2 3 1 2
chr1 200 3 4 0 0
chr1 300 0 0 4 1
chr2 100 1 4 7 5
chr2 400 3 1 0 0
chr2 500 0 0 1 9
```

Comment: `join` is *still* greek to me. I've never yet climbed that mountain.

Comment: Hi @glenn jackmann, its not giving the output as you mentioned. Instead it gives output like this. chr1  100  2   100  1
chr1  100  2   300  4
chr1  200  3   100  1
chr1  200  3   300  4
chr2  100  1   100  7
chr2  100  1   500  1
chr2  400  3   100  7
chr2  400  3   500  1
chr   loc  T1  loc  T2

Comment: @NareshDJ - you're getting the header on the last line because of your locale; add `LANG=C` or `LC_ALL=C` before the last `sort` e.g. `... | LANG=C sort`